# Gmail HTML Email overriden background color

Tags: css, laravel, gmail, html-email

I'm trying to send HTML Markdown Email with laravel to my Gmail account, all the other images are rendered correctly and have a white background, however, only the background image is enveloped in a black color as if I set the style to that (I didn't, in fact I even put "background-color:white!important;", inline, everywhere, to override this.)

Looking at Gmail's styles with dev tools, it seems their body has that bg color set. My question is, is this intended behavior and what can I do to override it?

On that note, the images with black bg are PNGs, so maybe convert to JPEG and fill in a white bg?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you could supply the original image, that might help -- is it possible that you have saved the png with the 'matte' as black, instead of white? The matte is the blend colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently i've used the webp versions of them instead of the png ones for performance testings, for some reason the webp transparencies are all black, so there's that.

Lesson learned: png or jpg only with compression for emails ppl.